# Jquery cycle plugin multiple pager in the same page

Tags: jquery, plugins, pager

I have a problem with cycle plugin multiple pager in the same page
I would like to show 24 cycle plugin in the same page. Each plugin contains some picture and information. So I would like to control each other with "pager". Everything is OK, all plugins it works simple document ready function. But I have a quite different problem with pager.

When I try to add `pager:"#nav"` and `.before("<div id="nav"></div>")` in the plugin's function. The script creates a container like this `<div id="nav"></div>` and then plugin appends all pager links in this container. So All pagers links shows in the one container id it causes like this.

http://onur.mayanet.com.tr/test

I want access to something that each plugin should work with its own pager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs in a page have to be unique, so change this:

```
$('.slideshow').before('<div id="nav"></div>').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    speed: 'fast',
    timeout: 350,
    pager: "#nav"
});
```

To this:

```
$('.slideshow').each(function() {
  $(this).before('<div class="nav"></div>').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollLeft',
    speed: 'fast',
    timeout: 350,
    pager: $(this).prev()
  });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Qnwub/1/), all we're doing here is looping through and creating/assigning a pager to each one, rather than using an `id` which has to be unique.  Be sure to change your `#nav` CSS rules to `.nav` to match the `id` => `class` change as well.

Comment: @Onur - welcome, if that resolved your issue please mark this as accepted so it helps the next person (via the checkmark on the left).  If it gives other issues please comment again so I an help out :)